# TMSL Creating Multiple Partitions Unrecognised JSON property

Tags: ssas-tabular

Hi all I'm trying to put together a script to create multiple partitions within a tabular data model.  I can do one at a time, but multiples seems to be erroring with the following message. 
Unrecognized JSON property: partitions. Check path 'create.partitions'

I'm using the following (anonymised) generated script.

```
{
    "create": {
        "parentObject": {
            "database": "MY_TABULAR",
            "table": "MY_TABLE"
        },
        "partitions": [{
            "name": "MY_TABLE 12 2018-09",
            "source": {
                "query": "SELECT * FROM [Fact].[MY_TABLE] WHERE PlanKey = 12 AND dateKey BETWEEN 20180901 AND 20180930",
                "dataSource": "MY_DW"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "MY_TABLE 12 2018-10",
            "source": {
                "query": "SELECT * FROM [Fact].[MY_TABLE] WHERE PlanKey = 12 AND dateKey BETWEEN 20181001 AND 20181031",
                "dataSource": "MY_DW"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "MY_TABLE 12 2018-11",
            "source": {
                "query": "SELECT * FROM [Fact].[MY_TABLE] WHERE PlanKey = 12 AND dateKey BETWEEN 20181101 AND 20181130",
                "dataSource": "MY_DW"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell from looking at the references this is correct, but SSMS doesn't appear to like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `Sequence` command to execute multiple `CreateOrReplace` commands that will create the partitions.  The `Sequence` command does have an optional `maxParallelism` property, however only refresh operations run in parallel (per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models-scripting-language-commands/sequence-command-tmsl?view=sql-server-2017)).  The example below details this further.

```
{
"sequence":
{
"operations": [
{
"createOrReplace": {
"object": {
"database": "YourTabularDatabase",
"table": "YourTable",
"partition": "Partition 1"
},
"partition": {
"name": "Partition 1",
"dataView": "full",
"source": {
"query": "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SourceTable] where DateKey < 20180901",
        "dataSource": "YourDataSource"
          }   
      }  
   }  
        },
    {
  "createOrReplace": {
    "object": {
      "database": "YourTabularDatabase",
      "table": "YourTable",
      "partition": "Partition 2"
    },
    "partition": {
      "name": "Partition 2,
      "source": {
 "query": "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SourceTable] where DateKey >= 20180901",
 "dataSource": "YourDataSource"
            }   
        }   
       }    
      }] 
 } 
}
```

Comment: That works using createOrReplace in sequence, but swapping it out with create doesn't work. I know the block is fine because it worked perfectly fine with a single partition, but it wouldn't work with multiples. I wonder what the differences are between create and createOrReplace as I know the partitions didn't exist before.